# Obtain Mean Field Equations for Spin Models using a uniform Ansatz

Tags: phase-transition, ising-model, mean-field-theory

I would like to see how my model I am working on behaves in the limit of infinite dimensions so I get a little bit of intuition for the low dimensional case.  In the paper I am reading they have a transverse Ising model:

$
H = -J \sum_{<i,j>}\sigma_i^x \sigma_j^x+\Delta \sum_i \sigma_i^z 
$

with an additional way of spontaneous emission with Lindblad operators $L_i = \sqrt{\Gamma} \sigma_i^-$ so the dynamics are governed by the master equation.
They just take it for granted that using a "uniform ansatz" one gets the MF equation:

$
\frac{d}{dt} X = - \Delta Y - \frac{\Gamma}{2} X 
$

where $X=\langle \sigma_x \rangle$.

What does this uniform ansatz mean in this context? I only know that MF usually means that one replaces the spins with the average magnetization and as such can reduce the problem to an easier one where the spins only feel an effective magnetic field.

Or is it really easy to obtain this equation?

Comment: It is not true that MF just replaces spins with average magnetization. Rather, you expand $s = \langle s\rangle + \delta s$ and neclect terms quadratic in $\delta s$.

Comment: True! That was badly formulated. But the question remains.

Comment: What is Y? What did you try? And could you please link the paper?

Comment: Note that a lot of information in the question is missing, e.g. what does one want to capture? (When I hear MF, I think of the ground state. But, apparently, time evolution?)

Comment: Sorry! I thought the implication was clear that with $Y$ I mean $\langle \sigma_y \rangle$ similar to $X$ but I see that it was not. Here is the link to the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01939. The question is about page 5 right side: Mean Field, where the equation I gave is in Appendix A on page 14 top right corner.

Comment: This is weird, how can <Y> appear if it does not appear in the Hamiltonian?  (I mean, H is invariant under complex conjugation while Y isn't ... )

Comment: I found out if you write $ \dot{X}=\text{Tr}(\rho \sigma_x$) then you can use the Lindblad equation to express the r.h.s in terms of the other Pauli matrices. For example, the ferromagnetic part in the hamiltonian commutes with $\sigma_x$ and hence gives no contribution. The external field $\sim \sigma_z$ gives $\sigma_y$ with the commutator. I think the other terms appear similarly.